# Initializing static 2D array

Tags: c++, arrays, static

This following code:

```
enum Type {Prince, Princess, King, Queen, NumTypes};
enum Country {England, Belgium, Netherlands, NumCountries};

class Factory {
    static const std::array<std::array<int, NumTypes>, NumCountries> probabilities;
    static std::array<std::array<int, NumTypes>, NumCountries> initializeProbabilities() {
        std::array<std::array<int, NumTypes>, NumCountries> p;
        p[England] =     {29, 60, 80, 100};
        p[Belgium] =     {31, 66, 81, 100};
        p[Netherlands] = {25, 45, 90, 100};
      return p;
    }
};
const std::array<std::array<int, NumTypes>, NumCountries> Factory::probabilities = initializeProbabilities();
```

is safe if I ever change the order of elements in enum Country, but it is not safe from any future reordering of enum Type elements.  What is the best way to avoid that problem without initializing all 12 elements one by one?

Comment: You could use a map...

Comment: @ Brian. But isn't that simply assigning all 12 elements one by one? Isn't there a way to do it without assigning each element individually?  Imagine the matrix is 12 by 30!

Comment: If you have C++11 support (which you obviously do, given `std::array`), you can initialize maps with braced-init-lists.

Comment: But that would still force the first number to be Prince, the second Princess, etc..., so it faces the same problem as my code above.

Comment: No, it wouldn't. You initialize a map with a list of pairs.

Comment: It isn't safe, but if you are looking to protect yourself against reordering, then you can use a static assert to check the ordering that you assume.

Answer (score 1):

In order to avoid dependency on the order, you should write something like:

```
p[England][Prince]=29;
p[England][Princess]=60;
p[England][King]=80;
p[England][Queen]=100;

p[Belgium][Prince]=31;
p[Belgium][Princess]=66;
p[Belgium][King]=81;
p[Belgium][Queen]=100;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution suggested by Brian (I think this is what he meant).  Is this probably the best way to solve the issues described?

```
enum Type {Prince, Princess, King, Queen, NumTypes};
enum Country {England, Belgium, Netherlands, NumCountries};

class Factory {
    static const std::array<std::map<Type, int>, NumCountries> probabilities;
    static std::array<std::map<Type, int>, NumCountries> initializeProbabilities() {
        std::array<std::map<Type, int>, NumCountries> p;
        p[England] =     { {Prince, 29}, {Princess, 60}, {King, 80}, {Queen, 100} };
        p[Belgium] =     { {Prince, 31}, {Princess, 66}, {King, 81}, {Queen, 100} };
        p[Netherlands] = { {Prince, 25}, {Princess, 45}, {King, 90}, {Queen, 100} };
        return p;   
    }
};
const std::array<std::map<Type, int>, NumCountries> Factory::probabilities = initializeProbabilities();
```

Or perhaps he meant map of a map.